Expressing synchrotron radiation, bending magnet flux
In chapter 14 of Jackson the number of photons per unit frequency interval is given by:

How can I go from $\frac{photons}{d \omega}$ to a flux expressed in photons per second per 0.1% bandwith $\frac{photons}{s \cdot 0.1\%BW}$ where 0.1%BW is the energy bandwidth equal to $0.001 = \frac{\Delta E}{E}$.
Is all I have to do just re-arrange the equation to have $\frac{dN}{\frac{\Delta E}{E}}$? Is that it? Then obviously the experiment (simulation in my case) done over a second will give us the per second.
This will be the bending magnet's flux, correct?
The more details the better, thank you.

@ghoster helped me out in my previous question 2 weeks ago
